# SPListItem.Update() not firing ItemUpdating

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I'm updating item in SPListItemCollection using SPListItem.Upadte() but my event receiver is not receiving ItemUpdating/ItemUpdated events (breakpoints are not hit on either handlers).

Sample code that fails to invoke itemupdating event:

```
SPListItem opFolder = list.Folders.Add(strURL, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, strNewName);

opFolder["ContentTypeId"] = strNewContentType;
opFolder["ParentID"] = spf["NodeID"].ToString();
opFolder.Update();
```

Comment: And you are sure you are not calling DisableEventFiring() before SPListItem.Upadte()?

Comment: How did you register the event receiver?

Comment: @JamesLove I've run it from VS2010. Receiver is working since i'm receiving ItemAdding from that same piece of code (im calling SPList.Folders.Add which fires itemadding before calling update on splistitem). Also itemupdating is fired when i add new item from SP DocLibrary itself.

Comment: @Diptarag Nope, there is no DisableEventFiring call in the receiver or in webpart.

Comment: Can you post your sample code here so that we can have a look

Comment: try to start the debugger with a Debugger.Break or similar in the event handler code, so we can exclude that the problem is caused your debugger begin attached to the wrong process (since I have seen that behaviour in visual studio in the past).

Comment: debugger is attached to the correct process. it receives adding event from that same piece of code, but doesnt get update.

Comment: @Nemanja It might be you registered Item Adding, but not Item Added events. You can check registered events with PowerShell.

Comment: Which process are you attaching to to monitor the breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this code with Elevated Priveleges?

If so it sends a SystemUpdate() which does not fire events.

Comment: I've been playing around this issue, and i've found that if i execute Update AND SystemUpdate in succsession, ItemUpdating event is fired?

Comment: MSDN: "When you call the SystemUpdate() method, events **are triggered** and the modifications are reported in the Change and Audit logs, but alerts are not sent and properties are not demoted into documents." I checked in SP2013 - it DOES fire the events!