# c# Programmatic sub-folder creation with SystemUpdate

Tags: development, alert

Environment: SP2010 Enterprise, VS2012, full server access

Goal: Console application that creates sub-folders in various locations based on user input, and uses SystemUpdate(false) to prevent alerts from triggering.

Where I am thus far: I have a basic console application with prompts for user input and am trying to take that input (things like folder name, library name, etc) and use it to add specific sub-folders anywhere in the library directory structure. I have a code snippet that successfully creates a **new** top-level folder and then a sub-folder underneath it (using SPListItem the whole way), but I can't figure out how to create a sub-folder in an **existing** folder/path. The tricky part is that it has to be done with SPListItem, not SPFolder, because SPListItem has the SystemUpdate method that prevents alerts from firing, while SPFolder does not.

**Small clarification:** The sub-folders are going to go way down the directory structure, not just under a top-level folder.

Here's the code I mentioned:

```
SPList list = oWeb.Lists[listName];

SPListItem folder = list.AddItem(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, topFolder);
folder.SystemUpdate(false);

SPListItem SubFolder = list.AddItem(folder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl , SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, folderName);
SubFolder.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Ideas? Alternatives?
Thanks for your time!

**Update:** As I was writing this, another problem surfaced. It turns out the SystemUpdate isn't preventing alerts from firing in this case. I have used it in several other programs that change ListItem properties and it worked fine... What's wrong this time?

**More thoughts/clarification:** I see several people describing almost exactly what I'm doing here and it working. Specifically this post [SPListItem.Update() not firing ItemUpdating](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/52232/11647) which uses almost identical code to mine. The difference is I'm using ServerRelativeURL instead of specifying a URL. Does that have any effect on the ItemUpdating event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it. The sub-folder in which you want to create the new folder can be selected by getting a folder collection and then indexing it, like this:

```
SPFolderCollection oCol = oList.RootFolder.SubFolders;
SPFolder oFolder = oCol[oSubFolder];
```

...then adding it with the url like so:

```
SPListItem newFolder = oList.AddItem(oFolder.Url, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, newFolderName);
```

So now I'm just down to figuring out why SPListItem.SystemUpdate(false) is not working. It seems to just do a regular SPListItem.Update() instead. Will post this in a new question.